# Python script importing multiple files and save outputs

Tags: python

I would like to open several files and save the outputs. This is the operation that I would like to script iteratively for {i}=76 files.txt. The reference_file.txt is always the same for each of the 76 files I want to manipulate.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.loadtxt('filename{i}.txt')
b=np.loadtxt('reference_file.txt')
np.savetxt('output{i}.txt', np.subtract(a,b))
```

and then end the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping python using a `for` command. `range(0, 76)` is a `range` object. To keep things simple it's like a list of 0 to 75. That means `i` will take the values of `0, 1, 2, .., 75` each iteration.

Extracted `b` out of the loop since it's not depended on `i`

Using string `format` to use `i` in the string. read about it [here](https://pyformat.info/) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html)

```
import numpy as np

b = np.loadtxt('reference_file.txt')
for i in range(0, 76):
    a = np.loadtxt("filename{}.txt".format(i))
    np.savetxt("output{}.txt".format(i), np.subtract(a,b))
```

Comment: I suggest better variable names than `b` and `a`. Also since Python 3.6: `np.loadtxt(f"filename{i}.txt")`

Comment: I did not know that, and this is way more elegant than the format method I usually use

Comment: Also new to me! Thanks @Dan !